# Rails 3 - Setting up PhotoAlbum & Photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created:

```
PhotoAlbum (id, name)
  has_many: photos
Photo (id, name, photo_album_id)
  belongs_to: photo_album
```

I want to allow a user to upload 1 or more photos. Per Upload whether it be 1 or more photos, they should automatically be added to a new album.

So the way i have it is, a user clicks upload photos:
They get the photo view where they get the form. They can then upload 1 photo (in the future I want to support more than 1, but baby steps!

so now in my Photos Controller, I have DEF CREATE

Q: How in the DEF CREATE, do I auto create an album and then create the photos? Something like?

```
@photo_album = PhotoAlbum.create
@photo = @photo_album.create(params[:photo])
```

? Is this the right Rails way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@photo_album = PhotoAlbum.create({:name => "My Photo Album"})
@photo = @photo_album.photos.build({:name => params[:photo]})
```

I'm assuming your params[:photo] is the name, but you get the idea.